# how to insert paynow button in bounded gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to add pay now button as shown in bounded Gridview in asp.net.
I have used like following

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="challanstatus" 
    Width="646px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RegisNo" HeaderText="RegisNo" 
            SortExpression="RegisNo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reason" HeaderText="Reason" 
            SortExpression="Reason" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" SortExpression="Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateofChallan" HeaderText="DateofChallan" 
            SortExpression="DateofChallan" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
            SortExpression="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
            SortExpression="Amount" />

<asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible="True" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />


    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="challanstatus" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/Database.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblchallan] WHERE (([RegisNo] = ?) AND ([RegisNo] = ?))">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="RegisNo" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="RegisNo2" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

where i use

```
<asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible="True" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```

to insert button but it gives following error:

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField does not have a DataBinding event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ans :- to get value from row in variable

Bind button as like this

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Pay Now" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Amount")%>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Get value of this row on OnRowCommand event like this :-

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
 {
  decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(e.CommandArgument);
 }
}
```

hope this helps you to get value..

Comment: can you tell me your exact requirement?? what do you want to do..??

Comment: i have gridview in wich there are 4 columns in amount column there is an amount which is to be paid i want that a person who want to pay the amount just click the button in the same row then the value of amount is passed to a variable from where i will redirect it to the paypal.

Comment: you can do this on GridView1_RowCommand. if you get the value from above code than you have to only redirect your page on paypal.aspx like `Response.Redirect("Paypal.aspx?amount=" + amount);` and than on the paypal.aspx page get the value of quirystring and put this in hiddenfields and submit this form by javascript..

Comment: it is editing the row but not redirecting from it i think u are missing something in the button code in aspx page

Comment: i think you want to integrate paypal in you application so i am suggesting these link to you it helps you to integrate this.. [link 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers) [link 2](http://www.spiderweblogic.com/Paypal-Integration-Code.aspx) [link 3](http://indiandotnet.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/simplest-paypal-integration-with-aspnet-in-5-steps/) [link 4](http://www.codersbarn.com/?tag=/paypal)

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Pay Now" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Use this code after this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" />
```

i think it helps you!! reply if you face any problem..

Comment: i have used your code but there is no button only a column appears

Comment: can you help me more i want to pass amount from respected row to a variable on clickcing the pay now button ?

Comment: yes you can do this using command argument function. bind your value in command argument and than access this on backend..

Comment: can you give more description? please